# Uml Statechart diagram with multiple transitions outgoing from initial state

Tags: uml, statechart

I'm a novice Uml guy
I want to know if it is possible to have multiple transitions outgoing from the initial state in a statechart diagram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per spec, you need a single initial state (solid circle) with a single transition pointing to the "real" starting state, i.e. the state your system is when it starts. If you feel you need several transitions to several starting states, then either:

- You are missing an intermediary state, that could be quite trivial (e.g. "started")
- You might consider using a choice node (diamond node) just after the initial state, but it is not usually a good practice.

Comment: I think as you said, I'm missing an intermediate state. The statechart I'm modeling concern the subscription to a webapp using either Email address which require a validation of the email, or with Facebook which will log you instantly to the web app.